# Extraction of hour from datetime object in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, dt, hour

When I extract hours from 23.35 using `dt.hour` in pandas   it returns 0. But i want to get 24. How to do that?

Comment: Replace 0 with 24 after the fact?

Comment: No, because it will change the rows wrongly which should be actually 0 like 0 hrs extracted from 0:20.

Comment: Ah... use pd.Timedelta object.

Comment: How to use that?

Comment: Can you put in some sample data with both 0 and 24 and other examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['00:10', '12:30', '23:35']))
0   2022-04-18 00:10:00
1   2022-04-18 12:30:00
2   2022-04-18 23:35:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

hours

```
s.dt.hour
0     0
1    12
2    23
dtype: int64
```

An indeed, if you `round`:

```
s.dt.round('h').dt.hour
0     0
1    12
2     0
dtype: int64
```

what you can do it to convert rounded hour+minutes

```
s.dt.hour.add(s.dt.minute/60).round().astype(int)
0     0
1    12
2    24
dtype: int64
```